# ember-cli addon bower dependency

Tags: npm, bower, ember-cli, add-on

Ember-CLI 1.13.8

I'm having trouble loading an addon i've just created into a separate test app. (This is my first addon.)

Because i'm developing locally i used `npm link` like so:

```
    $ cd ember-cli-foo
    $ npm link
    $ cd ../test-app
    $ npm link ember-cli-foo
```

And npm has created the link under node_modules.

The addon also has a bower dependency. I read somewhere that the main index.js inside the addon dir should look like:

```
    /* jshint node: true */
    'use strict';

    module.exports = {
      name: 'ember-cli-foo',

      included: function(app) {
        this._super.included(app);
        app.import(app.bowerDirectory + "/foo/web/foo.js");
      }
    };
```

And a blueprint:

```
    module.exports = {
      description: ""

      afterInstall: function(options) {
        return addBowerPackageToProject("foo");
      }
    };
```

But when i try running ember serve ...

```
    Path or pattern "bower_components/foo/web/foo.js" did not match any files
```

Realising that i likely needed to point to the *addon's* bower_components, i tried prepending to the import path:

```
    app.import("node_modules/ember-cli-foo/" + app.bowerDirectory + "/foo/web/foo.js");
```

But that just got me:

```
    Path or pattern "node_modules/ember-cli-foo/bower_components/foo/web/foo.js" did not match any files
```

That path is correct, though. I then tried:

```
    $ ember install ember-cli-foo
```

... which produces:

```
    Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.npmjs.org/ember-cli-foo
```

Can anyone tell me what i'm missing? How can i install the addon into a test app using the local npm link?

### UPDATE

Perhaps i'ma bit closer. I found this tip t get ember to run the bluprint:

```
$ ember g ember-cli-foo
```

And indeed ember replied, "installing ember-cli-foo". However,when i run `ember serve` i get the same error about not finding the dependency, no matter the path i feed it. The page where i found the above tip suggests the same as what i'd started with.

Doing `ember install ember-cli-foo` still results in a complaint that the package can't be found on npm's server.

### UPDATE II

I deleted the app and started over:

```
$ ember new test
$ cd test
$ npm link ember-cli-foo
$ ember g ember-cli-foo
$ ember serve
...
ENOENT, no such file or directory '/home/bally/dev/apps/test/tmp/concat_with_maps-input_base_path-RopBTsxP.tmp/0/bower_components/foo/web/foo.js'
```

Indeed, tmp is empty.

```
$ ember install ember-cli-foo
```

Same complaint--trying to fetch it remotely.

Answer (score 0):

When doing addon development locally you have to manually create the entry in the conusming app's `bower.json` referencing `foo.js`.  Unfortunately you can't do `ember install ember-cli-foo` until after the addon exists on either github or npm.